# How to Compile C# using a Text Editor in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, sublimetext2, linux-mint

I'm a noob at Linux and C#. In Windows, I write C# in Notepad++ and compile using CSScript.

I installed Linux Mint 17 and I want to write and compile C# from Sublime Text 2. How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you ever do that to yourself

Comment: To close voter: This question does not appear to be asking for a text editor recommendation.  OP has already chosen Sublime Text 2, and I guess wants configuration help for setting up a hotkey for invoking the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

install the Mono framework (http://www.mono-project.com/)

i'm not familiar with Sublime Text but the Mono command line to compile *.cs files is `mcs hello.cs`

or you can just do everything in MonoDevelop (http://www.monodevelop.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for that. Look at https://github.com/chrokh/csharp-build-singlefile-sublime-text-2

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you be more specific? That page refers to cmd + b for compilation. What is the cmd button?

Comment: cmd is in mac, use Ctrl

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Emacs. Here's a link to the CSharp mode. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode